# Generating Even Random Numbers

Tags: java, random, static

I have this class which is used as part of a game. It needs to generate Random Even values, which is done by generating random numbers until the result is even.

Is there a better way to do this?

Also, I currently have the methods implemented as private instance methods, but should I declare `generateRandomNumber()` and `evenNumber(number)` as static methods? Will it have any benefits?

```
public class Game {
    //...

    public void opponentSaysEvenNumber() {
        int number = generateRandomEvenNumber();
        System.out.println("Opponent: " + number);
    }

    private int generateRandomEvenNumber() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int number = random.nextInt();
        while (!evenNumber(number)) {
            number = random.nextInt();
        }
        return number;
    }

    private boolean evenNumber(int number) {
        return (number % 2) == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I would declare them as `private static`; [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538870/java-static-methods-best-practices) provides some good information.

Comment: Just wondering, why not just multiply whatever number you receive from the RNG by 2?

Comment: Add 1 to the odd ones that is generated?

Comment: @WetFeet why "multiply by 2" when you can more simply "add 1"?

Comment: @lohoris Because the 'add 1' operation requires you to test beforehand whether you have an odd or even number, so it's one test and one add operation, or just one test and a null; 'multiply by 2' *always* yields an even number, so it's always just a single operation that can be reduced to a 'bitwise left shift by 1' at assembly level. I don't think it's possible to *get* much faster than that...

Comment: ... Except maybe using a bit mask to zero the least significant bit, come to think of it.

Comment: I also would recommend a left shift operation, and for completeness sake, would like to point out bitwise AND'ing with NOT(1) would work as well (in one operation).

Comment: @Shadur, beat me to it as I was writing the comment.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu Great minds think alike. :)

Comment: I suspect "multiply by 2" is the option that distorts the distribution of the random number the least, if that's important (although I can't really back that feeling up, but Math.SE would know).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes.  I would <del>go one step further and</del> declare your functions as `private static` <del>`final`</del>, if possible.  The combination of those <del>three</del> keywords means that the code would be unaffected by any instance variable, any superclass, or any subclass, and is also not callable by any code external to the class.  Therefore, the compiler has enough of a hint that it could decide to inline the entire function.

I would also rename `evenNumber(int number)` to `isEven(int number)`.  There is a convention in Java that functions named `isSomething()` return a `boolean` and have no side effects.  Your function meets those criteria.

To generate a random even number, you could just take `random.nextInt() & -2` to mask off the least significant digit.  That would be more efficient than looping, testing, and discarding.  In that case, the whole question about helper functions would be irrelevant.

It's bad practice to create a new instance of `Random` every time you want to generate one random number, though.  The pseudorandom number generator actually carries some state, even if you don't think of it that way.  You should therefore use a `private static` variable to store the `Random` object.

Comment: `final` does nothing to a **private** static method.

Comment: @omiel will the JIT still inline it?

Comment: Static methods are not part of the inheritance, so there is no way for another class to over-ride them anyway. That's why final is meaningless.

Comment: Would there be a reasonable argument that adding final improves future readability?

Comment: @200_success Welcome to the discussion about naming predicate-methods. codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39399/naming-of-predicate-methods

Comment: before using a private static Random variable, consider the following excerpt from the javadoc: Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs.

Comment: Once upon a time, it was a Bad Thing to create your random every time for two reasons: 1) it seeded off of system time, so multiple calls in the same time slice of system time granularity would result in the same 'random' result, and 2) garbage collection wasn't optimized for short lived objects. Now, random creature seeds off of time and an independent state manipulator to combat that flaw, and most modern JVMs can spin objects up and down without the massive overhead of old. I still don't recommend creating your Random inside your method, but it's near as Bad of a Thing as it once was.

Answer (score 22):

Declaring such methods `static` can increase the readability of your code. For the reader it will be obvious that the method does not depend on the internal state of an instance of the class.

Comment: What's more calling `static` method is a little bit faster (no implicit passing of `this` to the method)

Comment: @Adam I'm pretty sure that would get compiled out of the resulting bytecode.

Answer (score 15):

Your technique is inefficient.  To generate even numbers, just do any of the following:

- Mask off the least significant bit (`-2` is `0xFFFFFFFE`, or a bitmask with all ones except for the last bit)

  ```
  random.nextInt() & -2;
  ```
- Shift left by one bit using the bit-shift operator

  ```
  random.nextInt() << 1;
  ```
- Shift left by one bit using multiplication

  ```
  random.nextInt() * 2;
  ```

Comment: Well spotted. At least the op should write if(!evenNumber(number))number++, so he wouldn't generate other random number

Comment: Using a bit mask is not acceptable because it modifies the number distribution. Ex: random outputs 2,3 become 2,2. Shifting left or multiplying are the only acceptable way.

Comment: @Carl No it doesn't (at least not for positive integers - for negative or positive integers there might be a slight bias around zero, but this doesn't apply here). All even numbers still occur with the same probability (they all can be output by the PRNG outputting themselves, or the number immediately following them).

Comment: There's a little flaw, when you multiply or shift left, you need to keep into account that you are working on integers, not unsigned integers, and a overflow will result in change of sign.

Comment: @DarioOO Overflow doesn't matter. All three techniques result in 31 random bits followed by a 0 bit.

Comment: from that point of view you are right, but most random numbers assume positive result only. Take for example user wants numbers from 0 to 6, it will do % by 7. but since also negative integer is returned, due to % sign rules, the real result is numbers in range [-6,6].

Answer (score 9):

If you don't use any of the attributes of the class, then it means that you should probably put this method somewhere else. Maybe in another class, a `RandomEvenNumberGenerator` for example.

I've always considered static a bad practice. It opens the path to so many problems, semantic issues and "I know where you live" syndrome, which in turns make testing harder, etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate what the "I know where you live" syndrome is in the context of unit testing? Google did not help me out on this one.

Comment: Unit testing is testing each component, each class in total separation from the others, to avoid any incontrollable side effects. Typically, you will have a hard time testing a component that's using a singleton, because you can't easily substitute the singleton with something you control. The component "knows where the singleton lives" and addresses directly to it. The better way would be to provide an instance of the singleton to the object that needs it. In the code given, it wouldn't really hurt, but having `static` methods encourages this coding style.

Comment: No, if this method is used in that class by its methods and nowhere else, it should certainly be static private. This makes a lot more sense than having a static class full of disparate helper functions, or a different class for each helper function. Static non-private methods in non-static classes are a different story. Your argument against singletons isn't really applicable here.

Comment: "private static" used this way for helper functions is pointless and misleading. It can be considered bad practice. The word "static" adds uneccesary syntactic noise, and it might be taken as a warning that there is some kind of singleton mechanism hidden somewhere.

Comment: @jwg, I never advertised the `Utility` class. Of course not. Having this method as static in this class forces to recreate a new `Random` instance each time we call the method, or else we need to share it as static property (danger!). I agree with Ichthyo in that it adds unnecessary code noise.

Comment: The argument about unit testing is completely bogus: 1. Private methods do not need to be tested. 2. `Random` is a standard component which does not need to be 'replaced with something you control'. As I said, if the method were not private it would be different.

Comment: You need to understand that, when talking about unit tests, I was referring to `static` in general, not in this specific case.

Comment: Well then, your argument is that the word `static` (6 chars) makes the code unnecessarily verbose?

Answer (score 9):

Why not just double the first random number generated and return it? You will still have random numbers, their distribution is not corrupted and its faster.

```
public class Game {
    //...

    public void opponentSaysEvenNumber() {
        int number = generateRandomEvenNumber();
        System.out.println("Opponent: " + number);
    }

    private int generateRandomEvenNumber() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int number = random.nextInt();
        return number * 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using a [ThreadLocalRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html)

```
private int generateRandomEvenNumber() {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt() & -2;
}
```

ThreadLocalRandom was added in Java 7 and [solves](http://java-performance.info/java-util-random-java-util-concurrent-threadlocalrandom-multithreaded-environments/) a few performances issues with the Random object, especially in multi-threaded environments. Even if you're not in a multi-treaded environment, I think it is a good idea to use it every time. Furthermore the Api is nicer than the old Random one (you don't have to create the object, just use the static method).

Using `& -2` (or any other method proposed by [@wizzi poo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/39419/49356)) will ensure the generated number is always even by setting the last bit of the generated number to 0. This is better than doing a while as there is always the chance Random  could never generate an even number (highly unlikely).

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to mask to make your elements even. There are an odd number of positive and an odd number of negative values. This can throw you for a loop (no pun intended) by causing them to be slightly biased.

Instead, you want to provide a min and max and find an even number in that range. You want to do this by shifting (actually division and multiplication, but because we're dealing with a power of 2 we can do it with bit shifts) and not with rounding (which is what masking is essentially).

As a general rule of thumb, you don't want to throw away random bits when you don't have to.

```
private static final Random rand = new Random(); 

public static int randomEvenNumber(int min, int max) {
    if(min % 2 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minimum value must be even");
    if(max % 2 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Maximum value must be even");
    int range = max - min;
    int rangeHalf = range >> 1; // divided by 2
    int randomValue = rand.nextInt(rangeHalf);
    randomValue = randomValue << 1; // multiplied by 2 to make it even
    return min + randomValue;
}

public static final int randomEvenNumber(int max) {
    return randomEvenNumber(0,max);
}
```

Comment: To be fair, if you care that much about bias, you probably don't want to use `java.util.Random` to begin with. This would also be more readable and just as efficient if you did `* 2` and `/ 2` instead of shifting.

Comment: It depends what you consider to be "fair". Masking off the LSB (or shifting off the MSB) does pick numbers from the set of all representable even `int`s with uniform probability. However, since there is one more representable negative even number than there are representable positive even numbers, you correctly note that the distribution is not exactly centered at 0.

Comment: Instead of throwing exceptions on min and max, why not use the rounded values?

Comment: @Henek Min and max parameters typically use the following contract: Min is the lowest acceptable value, and max is the first value greater than the highest acceptable value. If min was not even, it would not be an acceptable value which breaks the contract. The case for max is similar. One could argue that those conditions do not belong there. For example, randomEvenNumber(9,19) might have solution set {10,12,14,16,18} - the logic would be slightly more intricate (determine if min is odd and adjust accordingly) but would not involve rounding.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a higher-level approach may get you to a better solution.

The random generator methods (generateRandomEvenNumber() and evenNumber()) are mathematical in nature and really not specific to the game.  They have no dependencies on the game class (e.g. they don't use fields) and they have no side effects.

My approach would be to do something like this.  Create a RandomService class with those methods and inject an instance of the service into the game.  Using Spring or some other DI (dependency injection) framework, the service can be created as a singleton.  The methods on RandomService can be public because they have no dependencies or side effects and they are easily testable, separately from the game.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a static and unique random number generator method is a good choice if you want to centralize the generation of those numbers. However, don't forget to also mark the method as `synchronized` if you're planning to run your code in a multithreaded environment.

You should also declare the `Random` instance as `private final static`.

Finally, as the `evenNumber` method consists of a single test, you could move that test to your `generateRandomEvenNumber` method and have your class composed by only two methods.

Another possibility if you want to centralize the generation of those random numbers is to create a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) random numbers generator.

Comment: I agree with you insofar the `generateRandomEvenNumber` should be moved out of that class, since it isn't related to the core concern of this Game class. But I disagree on the inlining of `evenNumber`. You loose the self-documenting through the name, and you force the user to figure out what the code does. And it would violate the "single level of abstraction" principle.

Comment: Nice point about the "single level of abstraction" principle, Jamal, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add or subtract 1 in case of odd random number.

```
...
number = random.nextInt();
if (number % 2 == 1) {
    number++;
    number %= MAX_NUMBER;   // assuming upper limit is required
}
...
```